# Get values of a key array by using the class name which one is similar to array name

Tags: jquery, html

I have a key array named as "type". The name of the array is the class name to a 'th'        tag. I want to get this array values by using the class name of the 'th' tag.     Is there any possibility to do this......

```
<script>
 var type= [{sym :"1" ,desc: "one"}, {sym:"2" ,desc:"two"},{sym: "3" ,desc:"three"}];
</script>

<html>
<body>
<table>
<th class="type">
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your array (or several ones) in an object, using class names as keys:

```
var arrays = {
    type: [{sym: "1", desc: "one"}, {sym: "2", desc: "two"}, {sym: "3", desc: "three"}]
};
```

Then you can simply use a class name later to get the array:

```
var typeArray = arrays[$("th").attr("class")];
```